# MVC 5 bundle config cannot find the Jquery images

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

I have MVC 5 Application and bundle JQuery and css in bundle.config and using in master.layout file. I am running simple test just to confirm that is all working but apparently cannot see images. where I am doing mistake. I am trying to find answer by reading other blogs but no good!

### output screen shot

[image]

[image]

### bundle.config

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css").Include(
                    "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/menu.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css",
                    "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
                   ));
```

### Master Layout Page

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
```

here is part of css code from theme.css

```
.ui-widget-content {
border: 1px solid #aaaaaa/*{borderColorContent}*/;
background: #ffffff/*{bgColorContent}*/ url("images/ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_40x100.png")/*{bgImgUrlContent}*/ 50%/*{bgContentXPos}*/ 50%/*{bgContentYPos}*/ repeat-x/*{bgContentRepeat}*/;
color: #222222/*{fcContent}*/;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the bundle to point to the root of the theme (base):

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/").Include(
                "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/base.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/draggable.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/menu.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/selectmenu.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/tooltip.css",
                "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"
               ));
```

and render it:

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/")
```

Comment: no still same result as I mansion in my output screen shoot; dialog box without x

Comment: I've edited my answer (put trailing /) also make sure you are not running in debug

Comment: no same result, I believe issue is not that because css style is applying on dialog, is just not picking up images... I believe issue with image path!!!

Comment: What is the url for the css when you view source?

Comment: I have update my answer... need to call bootstrap first before jquery ui.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer The reason this is happening, is because I am calling bootstrap in, after I am calling jquery-ui in.

Literally, swap the two

In master.layout page

```
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
 @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

This works!